# z3 python z3.If always False (keygen)

Tags: python, reverse, z3, key-generator

I want to generate a keygen in python with z3. here is the validation function:

```
def f(a):
    a = ord(a)
    if a <= 47 or a > 57:
        if a <= 64 or a > 98:
            exit()
        else:
            return a - 55
    else:
        return a - 48


def validate(key):
    if len(key) != 16:
        return False

    for k in key:
        if f(k)%2== 0:
            return False
    return True
```

I tried to write a solver for this

```
from z3 import *
solver = Solver()

def f_z3(a):
    return If(
        Or(a<=47, a>57),
        If(
            Or(a<=64, a>98),
            False, #  exit()???
            a -55
        ),
        a -48
    )

key = IntVector("key", 16)
for k in key:
    solver.add(f_z3(k)%2==0)

solver.check()
print(solver.model())
```

and here is the output

```
[key__1 = 48,
 key__10 = 48,
 key__9 = 48,
 key__15 = 48,
 key__6 = 48,
 key__8 = 48,
 key__4 = 48,
 key__0 = 48,
 key__14 = 48,
 key__11 = 48,
 key__7 = 48,
 key__5 = 48,
 key__2 = 48,
 key__12 = 48,
 key__13 = 48,
 key__3 = 48]
```

Which returns the key "0000000000000000", but validate("0000000000000000") return False.

I know that the problem is in the `f_z3` function, I don't know how to express the `exit()` inside the if, I want something always False. But instead am just returning False.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. As you observed, the replacement of `exit` with `False` isn't right
   in the `f_z3` function. (The python version is just bizarre here
   that it would return a boolean in certain cases and just plain die
   in others. But that's beside the point.) In all other branches
   you're returning an integer, and in that one you're returning a
   boolean. In z3 you always want to return the same type; an integer.
   So pick something that will cause that case to produce `False`
   eventually. Since later on you're checking for evenness, any odd
   number will do. Say `1`; so modify it to produce `1` instead of
   `False` when `exit` is called.
2. While you're validating, the Python code returns `False` if the result is even; so you need to assert that correctly. Currently you're doing `solver.add(f_z3(k)%2==0)`, instead you should require the modulus to be not-even, like this: `solver.add(f_z3(k)%2!=0)`.

With those two modifications, you'll have the following code:

```
from z3 import *
solver = Solver()

def f_z3(a):
    return If(
        Or(a<=47, a>57),
        If(
            Or(a<=64, a>98),
            1,
            a -55
        ),
        a -48
    )

key = IntVector("key", 16)
for k in key:
    solver.add(f_z3(k)%2!=0)

solver.check()
print(solver.model())
```

When run, this produces:

```
[key__1 = 49,
 key__10 = 49,
 key__9 = 49,
 key__15 = 49,
 key__6 = 49,
 key__8 = 49,
 key__4 = 49,
 key__0 = 49,
 key__14 = 49,
 key__11 = 49,
 key__7 = 49,
 key__12 = 49,
 key__5 = 49,
 key__2 = 49,
 key__13 = 49,
 key__3 = 49]
```

which suggests the valid key `"1111111111111111"`.

Answer (score 0):

For the second point I didn't notice, I was more concentrate in the first one.
returning 1 doesn't solve my problem sins I just simplified the real problem with a smaller example. I want a general solution for this pattern.

```
def f(x):
   if condition(x):
       exit()
   else:
       return g(x) # return something in relation with x
```

I found this pattern which is working now

```
def f_z3(x):
    global solver
    solver.add(Not(condition(x))
    return g(x)
```

So my first function will be something like

```
def f_z3(a):
    global solver
    # sins we have two nested condition we have to add an And
    solver.add(
        Not(
            And(
                Or(a<=47, a>57),
                Or(a<=64, a>98)
            )
        )
    )
    return If(
        Or(a<=47, a>57),
        a-55,
        a - 48
    )
```

I still search a better approach to solve this kind of pattern, something that tell the If condition to be always False.

Comment: This sounds like you have 'pre-conditions' on when the function `f` can be called. That would suggest the onus is on the caller to enforce that; so the constraint should move to the caller.